# Angular $http.reject vs. $q.reject

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I am remember researching this awhile back and coming up empty handed and I still can't find any good info on this - why does there appear to be a `$q.reject` method but not an `$http.reject` method?

For example, in real life we might have:

```
unfollow: function (userId) {

    if (!AuthService.isLoggedIn()) {
        //$location.url('/login');
        window.location.href = '/login';
        return $q.reject({error: 'no logged-in user, but non-existent user could still click a follow button?'});
    }
    else {
        return $http({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: ConfigService.api.baseUrl + '/v1/users/add_unfollow/by_id/' + userId
        });
    }

}
```

I would rather uses the relevant `$http.reject` instead of `$q.reject`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You never made an `$http` call so `$http` would not reject that promise. The way it's being done here is a fine way to do it.

Comment: What do you want `$http.reject` to be/do?

Comment: Would you expect *all* functions that return promises to have a `.reject` method? Such as `unfollow.reject()`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `$http` returns a promise in one leg of the conditional...the function itself needs to return a promise in the other leg also.

Using `$q.reject()` is simply a shortcut to return a rejected promise.

Without it, any place that calls `unfollow().then()` wouldn't have a `then()` method if a promise wasn't returned

Answer (score 1):

$http would wrap the http calls and return a promise. The promise would rejected if the actual http request is failed, and adding a reject method would not make much sense, rather it should be in the promise.

In your example you would not even need to call the $http service to reject the request.